# Почему добавление аннотации FormDataParam вызывает исключение при запуске REST-сервиса?

Tags: post, java-ee, rest, jersey, jax-rs

В [документации](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart) Jersey (версия 2.29.1) есть следующий пример `Example 9.50. Use of @FormDataParam annotation`:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String postForm(
    @DefaultValue("true") @FormDataParam("enabled") boolean enabled,
    @FormDataParam("data") FileData bean,
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition) {

    // ...
}
```

В моём случае метод выглядит следующим образом:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/test")
public Response saveFiles(        
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition
){
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

При запуске сервера (то есть до вызова метода даже не доходит) получаю следующую ошибку (использую Apache Tomcat/8.5.16):

> Type Exception Report
>
> Message Servlet.init() for servlet [rest.ApplicationConfig] threw
>   exception
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
>   [rest.ApplicationConfig] threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Root Cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not
>   modifiable in this context.
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:246)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:193)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:426)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:306)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:346)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
>   logs.

При этом если убрать `@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file` и `@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition`, то сервер запускается нормально:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/test")
public Response saveFiles(){
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Сам сервер настраивается без использования `web.xml`, если это имеет значение:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

}
```

Пробовал так, результат точно такой же:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig(){            
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    }
}
```

В чём заключается проблема и как её исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, проблема в классе `ApplicationConfig`.
Во-первых, класс находится в пакете `rest`.
Во-вторых, этот пакет нужно добавить в конструктор класса `ApplicationConfig`.

```
package rest;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig(){
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        packages("rest");
    }
}
```